# Linux, netstat : how to display the owner of programs using ports?

Tags: linux, networking, netstat

I'm getting crazy with the command `netstat`.
In the man we can read that, in the output of Active Internet Connections (TCP, UDP, raw) we should have :

> User : The username or the user id (UID) of the owner of the socket.

But when I do

```
netstat -natp
```

my output doesn't show any owner (or UID)

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)  
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4713            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2159/pulseaudio  
(...)
```

and I don't see any option in the man to display the owner of the PID.

There is the `--numeric-users`  option, but it doesn't change anything.

Is there something I'm missing? Or there is something wrong with netstat ?
Is there another way to get this information?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `netstat -natpe`.

From the man page:

```
-e, --extend
 Display additional information.  Use this option twice for maximum detail.
```

As clear as mud.

Which will add two columns, User and Inode to the display.

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      100        13119      1901/mysqld
```

Comment: Thank you very much yoonix. I've completely skipped this option as I was focused on searching for "user" and "owner" terms XD. I'll vote up for you as soon as I have a reputation of 15 ^^

Comment: Just thought it'd be worth noting that in case you can't figure who's who (like 0 is root) try peeking `/etc/passwd` in read mode ;)

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you could use `lsof -i` which shows you the user.

```
COMMAND     PID    USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd     32500  apache    4u  IPv6   14390      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     32501  apache    4u  IPv6   14390      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     32502  apache    4u  IPv6   14390      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     32503  apache    4u  IPv6   14390      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```